# Mystery/thriller Hong Kong/Japanese Movie with students disappearing

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, mystery

Okay, so I saw a hong kong(or maybe japanese? not sure.) movie on TV back in around 2003. I hadn't seen the whole movie back then so I would like to rewatch it agian. But, I don't remember the name of the movie nor the actors who played in it.

Anyways, the story takes place in some city/town of Hong Kong(or Japan). And five years ago there were a series of gruesome murders that took place in this city. But, the perpetrator was never caught since the killings stop as soon as they started. And just a month before the start of the actual movie, a column of light appears one night after which students from different high schools in that city/town start disappearing. The main character of this movie is a high school student who is trying to figure out the mystery behind the disappearance of his best friend and other students, who started to disappear a month after the appearance that column of light.

As the story progresses further we find out that their is also a some kind of new drug that's been circulating among the students and in the streets. And some of the students who have disappeared seem to have a link with this drug. Also, while the the main character is investigating the disappearance of his class mates, we also find out that there are a series of gruesome murder that have started to take place again. While the detectives who are investigating the murders acknowledge that the M.O. of the killer is similar to the ones that happened five years ago there are still some differences. The detectives conclude that it might be a Copycat. In addition to all this, there is also an urban legend floating around in the city regarding an 'Angel of Death' that is roaming in the streets. Unfortunately, this is all I can remember since I didn't end up seeing the whole movie. Since, I had to go to school the next day :P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the plot of the manga [*Boogiepop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogiepop_series), so this must be [Boogiepop and Others](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0331906/combined) (since it's the only live-action adaptation I know of) from 2000. The killings a month after a pillar of light had appeared, the students disappearing and investigating it, the new drug, the urban legend, this is all in there. You can read more about the novel [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogiepop_and_Others), and here's the trailer: